# Determine if ipv4 or ipv6 data structure

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

In a kernel module, given a `struct sockaddr` with `sa_family` initialized as `AF_UNSPEC`, how can I reliably determine if it is a `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6`? On Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae (x86).

```
    struct sockaddr {
                        unsigned short     sa_family; // AF_UNSPEC
                        char               sa_data[14]; // ?
                        };
    struct sockaddr_in {
                        unsigned short     sin_family;
                        unsigned short     sin_port;
                        struct in_addr     sin_addr;
                        char               sin_zero[8];
                        };
    struct sockaddr_in6 {
                        unsigned short     sin6_family;
                        unsigned short     sin6_port;
                        unsigned int       sin6_flowinfo;
                        struct in6_addr    sin6_addr;
                        unsigned int       sin6_scope_id;
                        };
```

Comment: why is sa-family set to  `AF_UNSPEC`

Comment: @GiuseppePes I don't know, it is given like that.

Comment: What's module? Custom or in mainline?

Comment: @0xAX I'm looking at system calls `sys_connect()` and `sys_sendto()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when something calls into the kernel and gives a `struct sockaddr`, it also has to give the length of the `struct sockaddr`. For example, see `sendto()`:

```
ssize_t sendto (int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t buflen, int flags,
                    const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

Using the size of the buffer, you ought to be able to get a good guess as to what type of `sockaddr` you need to use:

```
if (addr.sa_family == AF_UNSPEC) {
    switch (addrlen) {
        case sizeof (struct sockaddr_in): {
            addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
            break;
        }

        case sizeof (struct sockaddr_in6): {
            addr.sa_family = AF_INET6;
            break;
        }

        default: {
            // handle error

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In an ideal world, the `sa_family` would be set to seither `AF_INET` (IPv4) or `AF_INET6` (IPv6) already, but unfortunately that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Thank you. I know understand _why_ different structs are used.